# How to get a higher resolution on Google VR?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, resolution, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

I've been working with GoogleVR on Unity for quite a while now and the application I'm developing actually needs to be able to have a higher field of view than the one offered by Google Cardboard, since I'm trying to see my hands through the app and I need to really stretch my arm if I want that. I tried setting it manually by code and couldn't find a way to do it. I also tried increasing the resolution of the camera but also couldn't. I also tried setting a fixed DPI on the Resolution Scaling Mode on Unity, but then the GoogleVR framework broke and didn't work when I did that. I have also tried setting a custom cardboard profile and tested with a lot of different ones, but none of those increased the fiel of view significantly.

Does anyone has any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> You don't want to change "mockFieldOfView". That only affects the
>   in-editor FOV. The value you want to change is "matchMonoFOV" on the
>   StereoController. You also have to set a "CenterOfInterest" game
>   object on the StereoController. It makes the stereo FOV attempt to
>   match the FOV on the Main Camera (or whichever camera has the
>   StereoController script).

I think this is what you are searching for:
[Unable to change FOV of the google card board camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024935/unable-to-change-fov-of-the-google-card-board-camera/28040817#28040817)